# Need help proving this set identity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I need some help with this question for Discrete Math... It says:

> Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be sets. Establish the identity: $A\cap(B-C) = B\cap(A-C)$

Now I've worded what I have, but just let me know if I'm on the right track. Let $x$ be a member of $A\cap(B-C)$ such that $x \in A$ AND $x \in B$ but not $C$. So therefore $x \in A \cap B$ and not a member of $C$. Hence $x \in B \cap A$ and not $C$ to give $B\cap(A-C)$.

Comment: You've done half of it. Now show that every element of $B\cap (A-C)$ is an element of $A\cap (B-C)$.

Answer (score 1):

To infer that $x\in B\cap(A-C)$, you need $x\in B$ and $x\in A-C$. It's better to use these conditions although they are indeed implied by $x\in A\cap B$ and $x\not\in C$.

As for a proper proof of identities of the type set $M=$ set $N$, a rigorous way is to establish 2 inclusions: $M\subset N$ and $M\supset N$. That is, one can show $x\in M\implies x\in N$ and $x\in N\implies x\in M$.

In this particular case, both directions can be done via several uses of $\iff$:
\begin{align*}
x\in A\cap(B-C)& \iff x\in A \text{ and } x\in B-C\\
& \iff x\in A\text{ and }x\in B\text{ and }x\not\in C\\
& \iff x\in B\text{ and }x\in A\text{ and }x\not\in C\\
& \iff x\in B\text{ and }x\in A-C\\
& \iff x \in B\cap(A-C).
\end{align*}